# Creating documents sequentially using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have a model that looks something like

```
const NodeSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: ''},
    order: { type: Number, min: 0, required: true },
    parentId: { type: String, ref: 'Node', default: null },
});

Mongoose.model('Node', NodeSchema);
```

We validate that `parentId` is pointing to a previously added doc, using a Mongoose validation rule. The fixtures are all in a JSON file and they are sorted so that no Node is added before its parent.

We then load the fixtures using:

```
const fixtures = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync(file), 'utf8');
model.create(fixtures, next);
```

Our problem is that the fixtures are not being loaded in the same order they are on the file, and the validation fails.

Other than adding fixtures one by one (which makes for really ugly async code, even when using Async and Bluebird), is there a way of making Mongoose add the fixtures sequentially?

Comment: Have you tried `insertMany` instead of `create` to insert the documents?

Comment: The point being that [`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) is actually a "single call" to the database where [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) actually proxies "multiple" `.insert()` calls, which can complete in any order. `.insertMany()` does actually have an optional parameter for "ordered" which controls whether the "server" applies the operations in sequence or in parallel, and this would have an effect of not maintaining sequence where specified `false`, but the default is `true`. The differences are documented.

Comment: I have just tried `insertMany()` and has the same problem, validation fails because the docs are not inserted in the right order. It's a different document that fails each time, so they are definitely insterted in a random order or concurrently. On the Mongoose documentation it says that the `ordered` option comes from the [MongoDB driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany), where it says that it just doesn't continue inserting if one insert fails.